# Can you switch apps to use while the HUD is up?

Tags: hud

So for example; tap left alt

ITS FIREFOX!!!

No I don't want firefox, I want the hud for shutter!

BUT I DON'T WANT TO EXIT THE HUD TO REARRANGE MY WINDOWS AND SELECT SHUTTER!

so is there anything I can do to switch the apps the hud is displaying, from within the hud?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

HUD doesn't behave this way any more. They changed it somewhere on the way from Precise to Trusty. Since then, the HUD only shows results from the currently focussed application.